# перемещение кнопки пальцем андроид

Tags: java, android

Я хочу осуществить перемещение кнопки пальцем, но она странно себя ведет.
[видео](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv934vtkgfamn0z/error_dnd.mp4?dl=0)
`MainActivity.java`

```
package megapps.dragndrop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener
{

Button drag;
String msg = "set";
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    drag = findViewById(R.id.drag);
    drag.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.drag:
        {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - v.getHeight();
                    par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2;
                    par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawY() + v.getHeight()/2;
                    par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() + v.getWidth()/2;
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                    par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                    par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                    par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

`main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/drag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="megapps.dragndrop">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UDP**
работающая версия:

```
package megapps.dragndrop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener
{

Button drag;
String msg = "set";
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    drag = findViewById(R.id.drag);
    drag.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.drag:
        {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    v.setX(event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setY(event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()); 
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    v.setX(event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setY(event.getRawY() - v.getHeight());                         
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    v.setX(event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setY(event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()); 
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, оформите его в виде ответа (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос")